# Laravel 8 Components without Blade

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have created a basic CMS (Content Management System) using Laravel 8. I am not using Blade. All of my views are plain PHP and HTML. At this point everything is working but I have a lot of redundant code. Is there anyway to incorporate component like logic without using Blade? Should I just use PHP include statements? Is there a proper way to do this?

For example, I would like to move my header HTML to a separate `header.php` file. This would include everything from the `<!doctype>` tag to the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the proper way to achieve this, but the `view()` functions works from within a view file:

```php
<?= view('layout.header') ?>
```

Anyone see any issues with this?